# Python: find exact phrase in string

Tags: python, regex, string

I am not very familiar with string manipulation, and I am trying to find a way to determine if, given a text string and a phrase, that phrase appears in the string following the very same order it is given.

Example:
`string='This question will probably be down voted because I am not able to post a  minimal, complete, and verifiable example.'`

`phrase='I will not be down voted.'`

Since the `phrase` does not appear in the same order in the `string`, this is not a match. I know it is possible to find if a word is part of a string, such as:

```
if 'seek' in 'those who seek shall find':
    print('Success!')
```

but how to check if an entire phrase is present in the string with in the original order?

Comment: It is exactly the same, 'a  b' in 'a b c' will return True.

Comment: `if phrase in string:` ?

Comment: spaces are just another character, there is no concept of word boundaries in a single string and using the `in` operator, what is confusing you?

Comment: You have kind of answered your own question. For your needs you can just use 'if' and 'in'.

Comment: [This site](https://regex101.com/r/EWqTu6/1) can be helpful.  If you need the words to be in order just search them exactly using the ```re``` package. Otherwise you can put the words in there with ```.*``` separators. to do it dynamically if your phrase is a string then ```".*".join(s.split())``` will get you in that direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question very well but as someone commented, you can use the keyword `in` to test for a specific phrase inside a string:

`'my specific phrase' in 'my string with my specific phrase'` will return `True`.

However `'my specific phrase' in 'my string specific phrase'` will return `False` because even though the words are there, they are not in the same order.

Answer (score 2):

If I am getting it right, you can do that as you did to find a word in a given string :

```
if 'who seek shall' in 'those who seek shall find':
    print('Success!')
```

correct me if i'm wrong about what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways that I can think of:

1. With in opetor:

   phase in string

2.With string.find(substring) - will return None if the phase is not in the string.

3. With re.search - re is package in python

re.search(pattern, string)